# Count no. of specific values in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, data-science

I am a newbie in data analysis stuff. I am trying to analyse a dataset using python. [image]

1. I want to count no. of 1s in survived column
2. No. of male , female in Sex column

`PassengerId  Survived  Pclass   Sex

    0            1         0       3   male
    1            2         1       1   female
    2            3         1       3   male
    3            4         1       1   female
    4            5         0       3   male`

I tried groupby() but its giving error.

`In[88]   titanic_data.groupby('Survived') 
 Out[88] <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000BFFE588>`

Please suggest solution

Comment: Can you show your efforts, also the norm is to provide raw data rather than an image of your data.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to paste raw data. I have posted it.

Comment: To clarify, it isn't giving an error. It is printing an object reference rather than a human-readable format for the table (because of the grouping). Edit submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['Survived'].value_counts()
df['Sex'].value_counts()
```

Comment: 1 problem per question, incrementing your requirements is poor form, SO is not a forum

Comment: @EdChum thanks for your suggestion

Comment: This counts total number of male and female but how about number of females in pclass1 and number of males in pclass2 etc?